# How to sort emails data using its color codes in emeditor

Tags: sorting, emeditor

I have this little challenge.

I want to ask, how do i sort the emails using the color code (light green) as stated in this picture  here [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUqZn.png]

I have tried to remove the non emails by scrolling through, but i need a solution that can make it a one click through sorting.

I will appreciate your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Replace dialog box and enter the following regex in the Find field:

```
^((.*@[^\.]*)|([^@]+))$\n
```

Change the radio button to Regular Expressions. This regex pattern finds any line without a dot after `@` or any line without a `@`. Note that you need the last line of the document to be empty as shown in line 7 of your document.

Since we are deleting those lines, the "Replace with" field is blank. Now click Replace All.